# Removing Hinge Joint from script doesn't work

Tags: unity, rigidbody, joints

I'm facing serious problem with handling hinge joints dynamically in Unity.

I made bunch of chains and they are all linked for make something like "sealed door".

When I remove HingeJoint component at the runtime from Inspector, chains were unlinked and everything works fine.

But when I try same thing in the script, sometimes it works and sometimes not(And most of time doesn't work). And some condition just doesn't work.

There are two chain links so I need to remove two hinge joints, one named chain1 and one named chain2.

This is the code what am I tried:

```
Destroy(chain1.GetComponent<HingeJoint>());
Destroy(chain2.GetComponent<HingeJoint>());
```

Above code is just remove hinge joints but it doesn't worked always. So I added some delays:

```
IEnumerator RemoveHingeAfterTime(float delay, Rigidbody chainRB) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    Destroy(chainRB.GetComponent<HingeJoint>());
}

...

StartCoroutine(RemoveHingeAfterTime(0.1f, chain1.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()));
StartCoroutine(RemoveHingeAfterTime(0.2f, chain2.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()));
```

Above code is just quite random, sometimes work sometimes not. Especially chain2 almost not works.

I adjusted time to fix this, but nothing works. "yield return null" or "yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate" also doesn't worked.

My doesn't worked means like this:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Also I toggled isKinematics and useGravity with same logic(just hope that physics works) but doesn't worked either.

I'm using Unity 5.6.1f1. Is this glitch? Is there a way to fix this?

Any advice will very appreciate it.

Comment: I've never seen a component survive a Destroy call. Can you describe the symptoms you're seeing in a bit more detail? Is the component still present in the Inspector after it should have been destroyed, or is there just some leftover physics effect even though the component is gone? Have you verified you're destroying the hinge off the right GameObject, that it only had one HingeJoint to begin with, and that no other script is re-creating it?

Comment: @DMGregory Component was destroyed but physics not working properly only when I remove from script.

Comment: @DMGregory I made some pictures to explain this.
http://photon.modernator.me:/album/rico345100@gmail.com/blog/unity/hingejoint-issue/1.png
http://photon.modernator.me:/album/rico345100@gmail.com/blog/unity/hingejoint-issue/2.png
http://photon.modernator.me:/album/rico345100@gmail.com/blog/unity/hingejoint-issue/3.png

Comment: @DMGregory First picture shows the target that I want to rid of hinge joint component.
Second picture shows that remove hinge joint from script doesn't work properly.
Third picture shows that remove hinge joint form inspector works fine.

Comment: Information required to understand your problem should be added to your question itself as an edit, not hide in the comments. ;) So, we could describe the problem.as "links of the chain upstream from where the joint was removed don't react after it's gone, but links downstream swing away as expected"? Sounds like the physics bodies might just be asleep and need a nudge to wake them.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks, and please understand, I'm not good at english so it is hard to explain my situation. Your word, that is exactly what am I facing. Also I tried to toggle useGravity and isKinematic in rigidbody after some delays still didn't worked as I wrote the question. What can I try something else? Have any suggestion?

Comment: @DMGregory How do I "asleep and need a nudge to wake physics bodies"? Any advice please?

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce this problem to test solutions to it. When I set up a chain and destroy one HingeJoint component via script, both sides of the break swing away as expected. You can try calling the [WakeUp method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.WakeUp.html) or applying a very small impulse to the body on each side of the break to see if it just needs to be woken, but since I can't replicate the problem I can't verify whether this can solve it.

Comment: @DMGregory Invoking WakeUp method didn't worked, but as you said I gave them little force, now it's working perfectly! Could you post your comment as answer? Many thanks!

Comment: Feel free to.do so yourself. It's a bit late at night here. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by give the little force and forcely wake their rigidbody to every chain over there when it unlinked!